# Find the derivative of $y= \frac{(4x^3 +8)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+2)^5}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can we find the derivative of 
$y= \frac{(4x^3 +8)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+2)^5}$?

so far this is what I have done, and am confused about what to do after?

[image]

sorry for the messy handwriting

Comment: May you show the question instead of the answer?

Comment: @ArianaGrande I think OP is asking "how do we find the derivative of $y$?"

Comment: @probablyme Oh, ok makes sense now

Comment: @ArianaGrande it is how to find the derivative of y, I am confused about this since I keep messing up on the quotient rule. Please help.

Comment: @SubhayNazir Oh ok, if you are solving the question, do post your attempt so we will point what went wrong in the solution, it would also help us by knowing why is it asked in the first place

Comment: Note that we all studied calculus differently, please either take a picture of the question and the solving attempt or typeset then out here

Comment: But after you have $\frac{f'(x)g(x) - g'(x)f(x)}{(g(x))^2}$ you are not stuck, you are done.

Comment: You could edit the previous question, it would immediately get shot to the top, no matter how old is it. There are also answers in the previous question, please refer to them

Comment: You are **not** supposed to make a new post about an old question. You are supposed to ask respondents for more details. Also, make informative titles and learn to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Just show your work. It's all we ask. Then we can pinpoint where it went wrong.

Comment: @FrenzyLi oh ok but I need help with 1b only

Comment: @SubhayNazir Remove `1. (a)` in this question. Or better, just leave the equation in `1. (b)` and remove the question number `1. (b)` Also, typeset your attempt into the post (I have to rotate my head now).

Comment: Well, you could cancel an $(x+2)^4$ from top and bottom.  And $5(x+2)^4$ mysteriously became $(5x+10)^4$.   And the "bringing out" of $(4x^3+8)^{-2/3}$ was done incorrectly, what should have been left "inside" is plain $4x^3+8$. But maybe better, unless you are required to simplify, or simplification is needed for further processing, is not to simplify.   My analysis is likely incomplete, I have real trouble reading what you wrote.

Comment: Do. Not. Reask. EVER! A rule strictly upheld. As a new user you probably didn't know, but may be you should have spent some time browsing the site and learning the local norms before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean
How do we find the derivative of $y= \frac{(4x^3 +8)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+2)^5}$?

The quotation rule:
$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$

The chain rule:
$f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$

So to solve the question, we apply the quotation rule first

Letting
$$(4x^3 +8)^{\frac{1}{3}}=f(x)$$

$$(x+2)^5=g(x)$$

By applying the quotation rule, we get
$y'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$

You can use the chain rule to differentiate both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}(4x^3+8)^{-\frac{2}{3}}12x^2$

$g'(x)=5(x+2)^4$

You can plug all of these into $y'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$ to get the derivative

Comment: use `$$ $$` instead of `$ $`

Answer (score 0):

Use this relation $$( \frac{f}{g})'=\frac{(f')g-(g')f}{g^2}$$
with
$$f(x)=(4x^3+8)^{1/3}$$
and
$$g(x)=(x+2)^5. $$
Also use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have optionnally two equivalent ways: $$(\frac{u}{v})'=(\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2})\\(\frac 1v\cdot u)'=(\frac 1v)'\cdot u+(\frac 1v)\cdot u'$$

You must get after some care in calculations $$\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{4x^3+8}}{(x+2)^5}\right)'=\frac{-16x^3+8x^2-40}{(x+2)^6\sqrt[3]{(4x^3+8)^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

When you face products, quotients, powers, .. , you can make life much easier using logarithmic differentiation. In your case $$y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{4x^3+8}}{(x+2)^5}\implies \log(y)=\frac 13 \log(4x^3+8)-5\log(x+2)$$ Now, differentiate $$\frac{y'}y=\frac 13 \times\frac {12x^2}{4x^2+8}-5\times\frac 1{x+2}= ??$$

Simplify (reducing to same denominator) and use $y'=y\times \frac{y'}y$ and simplify the powers.

Comment: is there a way to do without logarithmic differentiation? I have not learned that yet.

Comment: Yes, for sure ! Quotient rule plus power rule plus ... But, if you already know that $\frac d {dx} \log(y)=\frac {y'}y$ you know logarithmic differentiation